# Intellij javascript debugger can not find debugged sources

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I have a project with Java REST backend and HTML + JavaScript frontend, and I'm trying to debug the JavaScript part.

My project is build with maven and deployed as an exploded war. The debugging works fine only if I put the breakpoints in javascript files residing in "target" folder, e.g the folder that the project compile output goes to.

How can I configure the Javascript debugger with where my scripts are?